# Json data not saved to DB in PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am trying to make a functionality where I am sending **Name** and **Age** using ajax. The same is gathered by **PHP** and then stored to **DB**. I think I am doing it correctly but data not saved in database. Can someone help me out?

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'addData.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                age: $('#age').val(),
            }
        })
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<input id="name" type="text" />
<input id="age" type="text" />
<button>Click</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

//Parameters for connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test1";

//Reading json
$data_back = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

// set json string to php variables
$name = $data_back->{"name"};
$age = $data_back->{"age"};

// Create Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Creating Query
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (name, age) VALUES ($name, $age)";

//Running Query
$conn->query($sql);

//Closing Connection
$conn->close();

?>
```

**ERROR**

[image]

Comment: can you share your error from console.?

Comment: You'll want to parameterize your query, just inserting $name and $age into the query produces invalid SQL (and a good chance for someone to insert their own potentially malicious SQL)

Comment: @K.Uzair - shared it!

Comment: try removing double quotes around name and age.

Comment: take the comma off here `age: $('#age').val(), <<<<<<` and see what happens

Comment: @K.Uzair - Error got removed but data still not added in DB table.

Comment: you need to put quotes around strings in INSERT: `...('$name', '$age')...`

Comment: @Milan : Did, still values not added to db table ;( ...

Comment: insert quotes around you variables in VALUES Section as VALUES ('$name',$age)

Comment: and you get no error in console now? did you output you values if they are posted from ajax request.?

Comment: in the php file comment it all out and just do `var_dump($_POST)`; and see if the proper values come through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're sending data with jquery as json, php is still recieving it as a $_POST object. So, this should work:

> ```
> $name = $_POST['name'];
> $age = $_POST['age'];
> ```

Comment: This did it for me ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think your object $data_back is empty because of errors in parsing of data by function json_decode. You should try to use var_dump($data_back); exit; after json_decode or more advanced methods such as debugging.

Comment: Yes, I was getting blank rows inserted +1 for this analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the proper way to access data post json_decode

```
$name = $data_back->name;
```

I also recommend looking into prepared statements for the database query execution...Ok, I HIGHLY recommend you look into it.

Edit: Maybe try this as well: Replace file_get_contents() with `$_POST`;

Comment: You can also do `json_decode($data,true)` to return an associative array like this: `$name = $json['name'];`